# Database schema design for Shifts

Tags: mysql, database-design

I want to check that the schema I am going to use is the most efficient way to store the following data.

The data represents firefighters shifts. Each shift needs a certain number of staff at each rank (firefighter and cheif are the two ranks).

i.e. working from Ventrua on a Monday Day shift you might need 4 firefighters and two cheifs.

The number (of firefighters) that is required per shift varies depending on shifttype (day, afternoon or night), location (of fire station) and day of the week (dow).

The total number of records required to define staffing requirements for one location across all shifts across all ranks across the week thus becomes

7 (days) * 3 (shifttypes) * 2 (ranks) = 42 records.

This is a lot of records when 90% of the time the number of staff required is the same across the shifttype and the day of week.

I have created the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE locations (
    locationid INT PRIMARY KEY,
    location VARCHAR(100),
    CN VARCHAR(100)
  );
  
  INSERT INTO locations VALUES
    (1, 'FIRE/OPS/SANTAMONICA/ENG', 'Santa Monica Emergency'),
    (2, 'FIRE/OPS/VENTURA/EMG', 'Ventura County Emergency'),
    (3, 'FIRE/OPS/ORANGE/EMG', 'Orange Country Emergency');

 CREATE TABLE shiftstrength (
   ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
   shifttype ENUM ('Day', 'Afternoon', 'Night'),
   locationid INT,
   dow INT,
   rank ENUM ('Firefighter', 'Cheif I', 'Cheif II'),
   numberofstaff INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (locationid) REFERENCES locations(locationid)
 );
 
 INSERT INTO shiftstrength VALUES
   (1, 'Day', 1, 4, 'Firefighter', 4),
   (2, 'Day', 1, 4, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (3, 'Afternoon', 1, 4, 'Firefighter', 4),
   (4, 'Afternoon', 1, 4, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (5, 'Night', 1, 4, 'Firefighter', 4),
   (6, 'Night', 1, 4, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (7, 'Day', 2, 4, 'Firefighter', 4),
   (8, 'Day', 2, 4, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (9, 'Afternoon', 2, 4, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (10, 'Afternoon', 2, 4, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (11, 'Night', 2, 4, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (12, 'Night', 2, 4, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (13, 'Day', 3, 4, 'Firefighter', 4),
   (14, 'Day', 3, 4, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (15, 'Afternoon', 3, 4, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (16, 'Afternoon', 3, 4, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (17, 'Night', 3, 4, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (18, 'Night', 3, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (19, 'Day', 1, 5, 'Firefighter', 4),
   (20, 'Day', 1, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (21, 'Afternoon', 1, 5, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (22, 'Afternoon', 1, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (23, 'Night', 1, 5, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (24, 'Night', 1, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (25, 'Day', 2, 5, 'Firefighter', 4),
   (26, 'Day', 2, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (27, 'Afternoon', 2, 5, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (28, 'Afternoon', 2, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (29, 'Night', 2, 5, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (30, 'Night', 2, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (31, 'Day', 3, 5, 'Firefighter', 4),
   (32, 'Day', 3, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (33, 'Afternoon', 3, 5, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (34, 'Afternoon', 3, 5, 'Cheif I', 2),
   (35, 'Night', 3, 7, 'Firefighter', 5),
   (36, 'Night', 3, 7, 'Cheif I', 2);
```

The way I am doing it is generating a lot of records.

Could the data be flattened to have the number of firefighters and cheifs as a field on a single record?

Is there a more efficient way to structure this data?

Comment: in your `shiftstrength` table, instead of having a `rank` and `numberofstaff` columns, why couldn't you just have something like `numOfFirefighters` and `numOfChiefs` columns that would hold the number of firefighters and chiefs respectively? if you needed to have separate numbers for `Chief I` and `Chief II` just change the "chief" columns to `numOfChiefI` and `numOfChiefII` and store the numbers that way. then you would just have 1 row per shift

Comment: 42 records is nothing. The representation that you have chosen is the best: simplicity in the structure is always preferable to a complicated structure, even if it is at the cost of more records. You'll appreciate this when you start extracting data from the database.

And incidentally, it's CHIEF, not cheif.

Comment: @RayBond the way you have it is just fine too, because it allows for adding new types of workers per shift, but if you need to have the structure "flatter" then my suggestion above would work

Comment: What about if I added another value 8 for day of the week - where an 8 means "all dow" ?